# How to select the first child from all similar class in css

Tags: html, css

How to select the first child from all similar class in css

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="no-a-child"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
    <div class="child"><span>3</span></div>
    <div class="child"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent .child:nth-child(1) span {
  color:red;
}
```

```css
.parent .child:nth-child(1) span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="no-a-child"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

Here I want a red color:

```
<div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
```

Comment: According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) nth-child works as an example: "Specify a background color for every <p> element that is the second child of its parent:" using the code `p:nth-child(2) {background: red;}`

So, you should use `nth-child(2)`

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez I believe the question specifically states CSS here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to achieve this effect requires two stages:

1. Declare a style for a given class
2. Undo that style for all elements of that class which follow the first element of that class

**Working Example:**

```css
/* Declare a style for a given class */

.child {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

/* Undo that style for all elements of that class which follow the first */

.child ~ .child {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="no-a-child"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
    <div class="child"><span>3</span></div>
    <div class="child"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well, but i guess you want just the first class `child` to be in red, and not the class `no-a-child`...if so, just use this

```css
.parent :nth-of-type(2) span{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
      <div class="no-a-child"><span>1</span></div>
      <div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
      <div class="child"><span>3</span></div>
      <div class="child"><span>4</span></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's not necessarily `:nth-of-type(2)` … it's the first child that _**is**_ a `class="child"` which could be the 1st, 5th, 12th, etc. You wouldn't know which number to put in the nth-of-type

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first `div` that has class `child` you could try something like:

`div.child:nth-of-type(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a adjacent sibling combinator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator to target the next element after the `no-a-child` class element as that seems to be what you really desire.

I added another example (cyan color) that illustrates that option

```css
.parent > .no-a-child+.child>span {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.parent-second> div:first-of-type + div>span {
  color: #00FFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="no-a-child"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>4</span></div>
</div>

<div class="parent-second">
  <div class="no-a-child"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I interspersed other divs for a more generalized problem: select the first with class "child" regardless of other divs/classes. I added entries at `0`, `1.5`, and `3.5` all with class "other". With that,  `parent-second` still works while `parent` doesn't.